# rake db:migrate invalid schema error for role that owns the schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu

In my `database.yml`

```
  default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5  
  timeout: 5000
  database: postgres
  username: website

development:
  <<: *default
  host: localhost
  password: password
  schema_search_path: "website_dev"
```

In the postgres database as admin user I run

```
ubuntu=# CREATE USER website WITH PASSWORD 'password';
CREATE ROLE
ubuntu=# CREATE SCHEMA website_dev AUTHORIZATION website;
CREATE SCHEMA
ubuntu=# CREATE SCHEMA website_test AUTHORIZATION website;                                                                               
CREATE SCHEMA
```

This should mean the user/role website can create tables in both the schemas website_dev and website_test, however rake db:migrate task fails with the error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidSchemaName: ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in
: CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" character varying PRIMARY KEY)
```

Comment: hi did you find the answer to this? i'm getting the same error

Comment: Yup I was facing this issue in cloud9.io as they have a different set of defaults for the postgres. I had updated my database yml accordingly to point to the right database and user. That temp space has been deleted now, so I can't share the ~/.profile file unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Pgsql SEARCH_PATH is not initialized before the first migration, even though it is defined in database.yml.

Here is the solution I would suggest, from my own experience:

1- create a **rake task** for initializing the database, which creates the schemas

2- run the first migration which creates the **schema_migrations** table

File lib/tasks/db.rake

```
namespace :db do
    desc 'Create database schemas before going for the first migration'
    task init: ['db:drop','db:create'] do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("CREATE SCHEMA website_dev AUTHORIZATION website")
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("CREATE SCHEMA website_test AUTHORIZATION website")
    puts 'Database initialised'
    end
  end
```

Running `rake db:init` will execute tasks db:drop, db:create, and then the instructions within the block. Running `rake db:migrate` right after this executes the migration on the first schema listed in the **schema_search_path: "website_dev"** directive of the corresponding environment in the database.yml file.